# After adding shared_preferences, I cannot build iOS simulator of Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

After I added shared_preferences to pubspec.yaml, iOS sumulator never success to build.

I tried

- flutter clean
- upgrade cocoapods
- pod install
- pod uninstall
- pod deintegrate

But none of them resolved this problem.

### versions

```
~/i/fissus ❯❯❯ flutter --version                                                                                                                    master ✱
Flutter 0.10.1-pre.45 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision bdc3dda5f2 (2 days ago) • 2018-10-15 15:03:02 -0700
Engine • revision 32f417db0d
Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.7.1.flutter-b99bcfd309
~/i/fissus ❯❯❯ dart --version                                                                                                                       master ✱
Dart VM version: 2.0.0 (Fri Aug 3 10:53:23 2018 +0200) on "macos_x64"
~/i/fissus ❯❯❯ pod --version                                                                                                                        master ✱
1.5.3
```

### pubspec.yaml

```
name: fproject
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.19.0 
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.1.0
  http: ^0.12.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Noto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf
        - asset: fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-Bold.otf
```

### error message

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
ERROR: Invalid version /Users/ryu.ishikawa/issus/fissus/ios/./Podfile.lock
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XS Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

### memo

I've read this issue, but I cannot resolve this.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10089

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this problem is not caused by Flutter.

**GVM(a version management tool of go) overrides diff command.**

So, `diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null` always failed.

```
$ cd /Users/#{your_user_name}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-{some_hash}/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build
# there are some .sh file. one of them.
$ cat Script-527F3B8B313E5250A155F99B.sh


#!/bin/sh
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
# This output is used by Xcode 'outputs' to avoid re-running this script phase.
echo "SUCCESS" > "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
```

### to fix

configure .zshrc or so on to use default diff command.